# Why does GCC need to clear edx for mysterious reasons?

Tags: optimization, gcc, assembly

Consider the following code:

```
int isqrt(int x) {
    unsigned int r;

    r = x >> 7;

    r += x / r;
    r >>= 1;
    r += x / r;
    r >>= 1;
    r += x / r;
    r >>= 1;

    return r;
}
```

`gcc -O3 isqrt.c -S` generates this:

```
_isqrt:
    pushl   %ebx
    movl    8(%esp), %ecx
    movl    %ecx, %ebx
    sarl    $7, %ebx
    movl    %ecx, %eax
    xorl    %edx, %edx  ; huh?
    divl    %ebx
    addl    %eax, %ebx
    shrl    %ebx
    movl    %ecx, %eax
    xorl    %edx, %edx  ; huh?
    divl    %ebx
    addl    %eax, %ebx
    shrl    %ebx
    movl    %ecx, %eax
    xorl    %edx, %edx  ; huh?
    divl    %ebx
    addl    %ebx, %eax
    shrl    %eax
    popl    %ebx
    ret
```

Why does it clear `%edx` for seamingly no reason 3 times?

Comment: Cause you're not supposed to use `-O3`, maybe? ;-)

Comment: Because `divl` has `%edx` as input *and output*.

Comment: @harold: exactly how is `%edx` used as input?

Comment: @harold: never mind, found it out - it takes a double word. Post it as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`divl x` divides `%edx:%eax` by `x`, so `%edx` should be something that makes sense (often zero). It also puts the remainder in `%edx` so it has to be cleared again, not just once.

Comment: and if not zero, %edx should be chosen so that the quotient of the division fits in 32 bits, otherwise an exception is raised. In other words, %edx should be smaller than the divisor